# Compiling this bash command

Tags: linux, bash

For my openVPN configuration, I'm trying to hit this code but it's not working.
Not a big fan of Bash command so I need to help to get this compiled. Any Ideas? (Currently using Kali linux and every time I hit this code it shows error message `bash: syntax error near unexpected token &&`)

```
echo "Enter clientName:" && set CLIENTNAME = $< && printf "\n<ca>\n" >> ./client.conf && cat ./ca.crt >> ./client.conf && printf "</ca>\n" >> ./client.conf && printf "\n<cert>" >> ./client.conf && grep -v '^ ' ./$CLIENTNAME.crt | grep -v 'Certificate' >> ./client.conf && printf "</cert>\n" >> ./client.conf && printf "\n<key>\n" >> ./client.conf && cat ./$CLIENTNAME.key >> ./client.conf && printf "</key>\n" >> ./client.conf
```

Comment: I fail to understand the connection between "bash command" and "compile"...

Comment: What is `$<` supposed to do?

Comment: I to am curious what set CLIENTNAME = $< is supposed to be doing?  Also, are you aware that virtually all of your commands will never error?  This means that most, if not all, of the && are not required.  The echo at the start also seems redundant, as en echo does not allow a user to enter anything

Comment: So you mean that i wouldn`t need any echo sign? And get rid of &&signs to fix the problem? I`ll try that and I`ll tell you if that works or not.

Comment: Just in case you guys wonder what that piece of code comes from, I`ll give my url that gives all the insturction for configuration https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-and-connect-to-a-private-openvpn-server-on-freebsd-10-1#step-7-—-starting-openvpn

Comment: @TheodoreShin You missed the very first instruction, before step 1: run `sudo tcsh`.

Comment: Also, if the instructions you're trying to follow are for [tag:FreeBSD], why is this question tagged [tag:linux]? Please have a look at the tag descriptions to determine what tags are appropriate for your question. This question, for example, isn't programming-related, so it might be better placed at a different StackExchange site altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this is not Bash code; it is [Tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) code:

```
$ echo $0
-bash
$ echo "Enter clientName:" && set CLIENTNAME = $< && printf "\n<ca>\n" >> ./client.conf && cat ./ca.crt >> ./client.conf && printf "</ca>\n" >> ./client.conf && printf "\n<cert>" >> ./client.conf && grep -v '^ ' ./$CLIENTNAME.crt | grep -v 'Certificate' >> ./client.conf && printf "</cert>\n" >> ./client.conf && printf "\n<key>\n" >> ./client.conf && cat ./$CLIENTNAME.key >> ./client.conf && printf "</key>\n" >> ./client.conf
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

Change shell:

```
$ tcsh
% echo $0
tcsh
% echo "Enter clientName:" && set CLIENTNAME = $< && printf "\n<ca>\n" >> ./client.conf && cat ./ca.crt >> ./client.conf && printf "</ca>\n" >> ./client.conf && printf "\n<cert>" >> ./client.conf && grep -v '^ ' ./$CLIENTNAME.crt | grep -v 'Certificate' >> ./client.conf && printf "</cert>\n" >> ./client.conf && printf "\n<key>\n" >> ./client.conf && cat ./$CLIENTNAME.key >> ./client.conf && printf "</key>\n" >> ./client.conf
Enter clientName:
foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I`ll try this one ! And I`m pretty sure this will work out. Have a great one

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial assumes you are using `tcsh`, not `bash` or any other POSIX-compatible shell. That said, you can make it work in `bash` by replacing

```
set CLIENTNAME = $<
```

with

```
IFS= read -r CLIENTNAME
```